# Using bitmap font for displaying and editing texts

Tags: android

One of the problems i'm facing now, is displaying complex texts (English + Persian/Arabic).
The texts which have both English and Persian/Arabic letters, not display in correct order.
For solving this issue, I created a Bitmap Font library that draws these complex texts correctly. Now i want to convert all the texts in all of my program's widgets to their bitmap equivalent. For example, if i have a TextView in my program, i want to get it's text, convert it to a bitmap with my bitmap font library and finally replace it in the TextView. The problem is finding a general solution which can be applied to any widget that can display text, like ListView, EditText, Menus, ...

[image]

Comment: Maybe you meant bi-directional?

Comment: Exactly. I mean BIDI algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try looking at the source code for TextView and modify it to suite your needs (ie, whenever a user enters a character using the IME, capture the event and insert the correct bitmap character to your custom view...)

Comment: I want to do this for all widgets, in your way, it will take a long time.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [Arabic Reshaper](https://github.com/agawish/Better-Arabic-Reshaper/) from all what I've understood it can be used to display correctly texts that contain both RTL (arabic) and LTR symbols.

Comment: This solution will fix words shaping, not words order in a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You can use font library in c++ and render the correct font 
though bit lengthy